# ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to connect to a certain URL from PL/SQL:

I did the following steps

1. Created an ACL
2. Granted both connect and resolve privileges to my schema
3. Assigned the URL to the ACL

   ```
   BEGIN  
       -- Create new acl
       DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl => 'NiceACL',  description => 'My ACL', principal   => 'JOHN',is_grant => true, privilege   => 'connect');  
       -- Connect privilege
       DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'NiceACL', principal => 'JOHN', is_grant  => true, privilege => 'connect');  
       -- Resolve privilege
       DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'NiceACL', principal => 'JOHN', is_grant  => true, privilege => 'resolve');         
       -- Assign host
       DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'NiceACL', host => 'domain.com');  

       COMMIT;  
   END;
   ```

After these steps, I run the following query and I can see the ACL Created and granted to the schema, and the host associated to the ACL

```
    SELECT  acl,  
            u.username, 
            host, 
            DECODE(DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE_ACLID(aclid, u.username, 'connect'), 1, 'GRANTED', 0, 'DENIED', null) conn_privilege,
            DECODE(DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE_ACLID(aclid, u.username, 'resolve'), 1, 'GRANTED', 0, 'DENIED', null) res_privilege 
    FROM 
            dba_network_acls a, 
            dba_users u 
    where 
            u.username = 'JOHN';
```

But When opening a connect (via the schema John) I'm getting the error : ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

```
UTL_TCP.OPEN_CONNECTION(REMOTE_HOST => 'domain.com', REMOTE_PORT => 8080, TX_TIMEOUT => 10);
```

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the lower and upper port in `dba_network_acls`?

Comment: @Popeye yes. There are empty. Does this mean the user can connect to any port right ?

Comment: True for resolve but not for connect. And you should also check if there is another acl pointing to the same domain. Try to assign port for connect. 8080 for lower and upper port and then check.